# GNU Boot loader failed to load image - can't delete ubuntu from system

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi, efibootmgr

I've been using ubuntu dual booting with windows for over a year or so, but today I got this message when I tried to turn on my pc:

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt, buffersize 0
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Volume Corrupt
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt
```

and the pc kept rebooting over and over again.

I knew it was an issue with boot menu and since I don't use ubuntu anymore I decided to delete it.
First I deleted the partition in diskmgmt and extended it with windows partition then tried to delete the boot menu and all ubuntu files from the cmd.
went to disk part and selected the EFI part to delete ubuntu but I had this error message:

```
cmd.exe Corrupt File
The file or directory \EFI\ubuntu\grupx64.efi is corrupted and unreadable.
Please run the Chkdsk utility.
```

Now I want to know how to solve this and get rid of ubuntu from my pc.
and secondly I would like to know if I ever wanted to download ubuntu (without dual boot) as the main OS, Will I have similar issues or not?

I appreciate any help you guys can give.